# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, foreach, operators

I get the following error :

```
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime'
```

---

```
 foreach (EndServReward r in reward)
                            {
                                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                                {
                                    con.Open();
                                }
                                myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = r.EmpNum ;
                                myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = (r.ServDate) ?? DBNull.Value;
                            }
```

---

where `reward is List<EndServReward> reward`,why this happens ,and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`??` is the null-coalescing operator.
It doesn't make sense to apply it to a value that cannot be `null`.

Comment: Why `r.ServDate` can't be `null` ?!! i want to check if those are empty properties or not set (filled) with values

Comment: @just_name This is why it cant be null : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: then what if i not set those properties and insert in the db ,Does this make any errors ?

Comment: `DateTime` is a struct which is guaranteed to be initialized with all zeros. All zeros equals `DateTime.MinValue` (0000-01-01) which is what will be inserted in the database.

Comment: @Corak - SqlServer will not accept a year before 1753 in a `datetime` column. It will reject a DateTime.MinValue (0001-01-01)

Comment: @HansKesting - You're right, of course. I'm too used to work with datetime2, I guess. So `DateTime.MinValue` is "what will be attempted to be inserted in the database."

Answer (score 8):

The nullcoalescing operator cannot be applied by default on a type that is inherently non-nullable like `DateTime`. If you wish to use it anyway, you'll have to foresee using `DateTime` as a nullable type, using e.g. `DateTime? dt;`

Answer (score 8):

Your r.ServDate property needs to be nullable:

```
public DateTime? ServDate { get; set; }
```

DateTime by default is not nullable

Answer (score 4):

DateTime is a ValueType. Value type aren't nullable -  they always carry some value.

This is the same for integers, doubles, etc.

The Operator you are using checks if the value is null, so it isn't necessary.

However, you might consider checking the value against a base value, like Min. You have actually to consider what is the default value of this variable, if that is acceptable, and then check against it.

Again, consider an int. You don't check it against null, but you may check it against zero or negatives.

Answer (score 3):

You can either change the type to nullable as suggested in other answers, or add a helper method like this to your code:

```
private bool IsDefault<T>(T value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return false;
    return value.Equals(default(T));
}
```

Then change the code to this:

```
myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = IsDefault<DateTime>(r.ServDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)r.ServDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out rightly in other answers you cannot use Null-Coalescing operator on a value type -DateTime.

Before you try to assign `myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value` with `Null`. First question is what is it you set the default value of `ServDate` property in`EndServReward` Class? Rather doing the conversion to `null` or `DateTime.Min` better set a default value for `ServData` when you create the object itself. This will help in deciding the functionality in one place and provide a consistent solution.

You can either choose it as `DateTime.Min` or `Null` when you create this rather than at the point of updating it to the database.